# Xamarin Forms - Handle Crossplateform Screen Variability

Tags: screen, xamarin.forms

One more time I'm coming here to ask a question about Xamarin Forms.

I would like first to speak about the differents screen. Android is perfect but iOS and WinPhone need some adaptation.. Whats does it means?

---

**Androïd**

[image]

*-The main layout is filling all of the screen.*

*-The top navbar is escaped, it's not a part of the screen.*

---

**iOS**

[image]

*-The main layout is filling the screen and the top navbar, so, the layout has to be adapted in consequences.*

To handle it, I add a simple margin of `20px` for the TOP

---

**WinPhone 8.1**

[image]

*-The main layout is filling the screen.*

*-The top navbar is escaped, it's not a part of the screen.*

However, on some Nokia/Microsoft Phones, the hardware button aren't present on the Phone. These buttons are part of the screen (`numerics buttons`), **they can be hidden but if they not, it takes part onto the screen...** and it's really boring.. **Some questions about it**

---

-How can I handle the coming of theses buttons? Does an `Event` exist to tell me when they are visible?

-What is the size of this Bottom Hardware Navbar?

-Can I do something which disables/hide this Navbar or disable the possibility of the user to disable/hide it?

---

Thank for reading !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using [Device.OnPlatform](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.OnPlatform/) for changes on a specific platform which do not require platform specific code. For the software navbar, I believe you can add something like this to your `OnLaunched` method in the App.xaml.cs:

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SuppressSystemOverlays = true;
```

See this SO question for more information: [Navigation buttons hiding Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822908/navigation-buttons-hiding-windows-phone-8-1)