# C# WinRT WP8.1 - Navigation Bar - Detect Physical/Virtual and/or Visible/Hidden

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

What is the easiest way to detect if a Windows Phone has the physical navigation buttons on the front of the phone, or uses the virtual buttons at the bottom of the screen?

I'm talking about the navigation bar with the back, home and search buttons.

And if the phone does indeed have the virtual navigation bar, then what's the easiest way to detect if it is currently being shown or not?

I'm looking for a full working example and not just links to other pages since I've already seen many.

UPDATE:  Not duplicate of:  [Navigation buttons hiding Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822908).
That question asks about preventing "shrink whole UI when virtual navigation bar appears".  I had already read that post a couple of times.  It is somewhat similar but not at all the same questions.  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigation buttons hiding Windows Phone 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822908/navigation-buttons-hiding-windows-phone-8-1)

Comment: It's not a duplicate.  Please see my reason above.  Thanks.